# How can I exit emacs without saving any changes

Tags: key-bindings, quitting

I would like to be able to exit emacs without saving changes.

I might have started editing some configuration file, then decided that I don't want to save the changes.

In vi I would issue the q! command to exit the editor. I don't know if there is an emacs alternative for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To exit emacs, use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>. It will ask you whether you want to save the changes. To prevent the question, precede the combination with <kbd>C-u</kbd> (but it will save the changes).

If you want to kill Emacs without saving any changes, you can use the `kill-emacs` function (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`kill-emacs`). If you need it often, you can assing it to any key combination you like.

E.g. add this to your init file:

```lisp
(global-set-key "\C-x\M-c" 'kill-emacs)
```

Comment: This also kill emacs daemon, how can I keep it alive?

Comment: Use `C-x` `#` to close a server editing buffer.

Comment: I am getting following warning message and nothing happens: `No server buffers remain to edit`

Comment: @alper: So just close the buffer with `C-x` `k`. But that's not the point of the question. If you're running in a terminal, press `C-z` to put emacs into background.

Comment: It's exact point of the question. I am using emacs to open `man` pages as `man-mode`. When I press `q` I just want to  exit emacs without saving any changes, but keep emacs-daemon running. I don't want to suspend because it won't close the latest open buffer

Comment: @alper: So write your own function that kills the buffer and then `suspend-emacs`.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, an emacs instance runs for a very long time: what comes and goes is the buffer visiting a file. So instead of killing emacs as a whole, it is probably more useful to kill the buffer that is visiting the file.

You do that with `kill-buffer` (usually bound to `C-x k`): if the buffer is modified it will ask you whether you want to kill it anyway and you can answer "yes".

Comment: This definitely the emacs style of doing the requested action. I will adopt this way of working. I accepted the kill-emacs answer because it answers the question (although the question might be ill formulated). Thanks.